# How to randomly click/check all radio/check boxes and select from drop-down menus in a webpage

Tags: html, javascript

Is there an easy way to randomly click/check all radio/check boxes and select random items in all drop-down menus in a webpage? I am testing my web site and there are a bunch of these. It is a pain to manually do all of these so I am wondering if some of you might have already coded up a solution (I imagine JavaScript would be the most obvious route) that is usable in all major browser/platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for automated web tests. It is quite powerful tool which can open the browser, perform various actions and assert some conditions.

You may also write some JavaScript that uses [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) to get all `<input>`s for instance, iterate over them and randomly check them.

Comment: see also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium